# A error about subfiles and tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, subfiles

I have a main.tex and a subfile. Subfile.tex file works independently, but when I run it with main.tex, the soft clip code gives an error. Is there any way to fix this? Where am i doing wrong?

My main.tex is

```js
\documentclass[10pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsfonts}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage[ddmmyyyy]{datetime}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xypic}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[turkish,shorthands=:!]{babel}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{10}

\usepackage{subfiles}


\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes, arrows, arrows.meta, 
 decorations.markings, patterns, datavisualization}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween, polar}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgflibrary{shapes.geometric}

\pgfplotsset{my style/.append style={axis x line=middle, axis y line=
    middle, xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$}, axis equal }}

\linespread{1.5}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Teorem}[section]
\newtheorem{acknowledgement}[theorem]{Acknowledgement}
\newtheorem{algorithm}[theorem]{Algorithm}
\newtheorem{axiom}[theorem]{Axiom}
\newtheorem{case}[theorem]{Case}
\newtheorem{claim}[theorem]{Claim}
\newtheorem{conclusion}[theorem]{Sonu\c{c}}
\newtheorem{condition}[theorem]{Condition}
\newtheorem{conjecture}[theorem]{Conjecture}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Sonu\c{c}}
\newtheorem{criterion}[theorem]{Criterion}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Tan\i m}
\newtheorem{exercise}[theorem]{\"{O}dev}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{notation}[theorem]{Notasyon}
\newtheorem{problem}[theorem]{Problem}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{\"{O}nerme}
\newtheorem{summary}[theorem]{Summary}
\newenvironment{proof}[1][Kan\i t]{\noindent\text{#1:} }{$\square$}
\newenvironment{remark}[1][Not]{\noindent\textbf{#1:} }{}
\newenvironment{solution}[1][\c{C}\"{o}z\"{u}m]{\noindent\text{#1:} }{}
\newenvironment{example}[1][\"{O}rnek]{\noindent\textbf{#1:} }{}
\renewcommand{\dateseparator}{.}
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\normalfont\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftsecpagefont}{\normalfont\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftdotsep}{1}




\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

\fancyhead[L]{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}

\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{
\markright{{\thesubsection.\ #1}}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}

\let\oldsection\section% Store \section in \oldsection
\renewcommand{\section}{\cleardoublepage\oldsection}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\title{\textbf{TOPOLOGY}}
\author{Dr}
\date{\today }
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}
\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}
\clearpage\null\thispagestyle{empty}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}} \clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\mainmatter
\subfile{subfile}
\end{document}
```

My subfile.tex is

```js
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage[ddmmyyyy]{datetime}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xypic}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{10}
%TCIDATA{OutputFilter=LATEX.DLL}
%TCIDATA{Version=5.50.0.2960}
%TCIDATA{<META NAME="SaveForMode" CONTENT="1">}
%TCIDATA{BibliographyScheme=Manual}
%TCIDATA{Created=Monday, November 25, 2019 14:11:36}
%TCIDATA{LastRevised=Friday, March 04, 2022 10:39:47}
%TCIDATA{<META NAME="GraphicsSave" CONTENT="32">}
%TCIDATA{<META NAME="DocumentShell" CONTENT="Standard LaTeX\Blank - Standard LaTeX Article">}
%TCIDATA{CSTFile=LaTeX article (bright).cst}

\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes, arrows, arrows.meta, 
decorations.markings, patterns, datavisualization}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween, polar}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgflibrary{shapes.geometric}
\pgfplotsset{my style/.append style={axis x line=middle, axis y line=
middle, xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$}, axis equal }}
\linespread{1.5}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Teorem}
\newtheorem{acknowledgement}[theorem]{Acknowledgement}
\newtheorem{algorithm}[theorem]{Algorithm}
\newtheorem{axiom}[theorem]{Axiom}
\newtheorem{case}[theorem]{Case}
\newtheorem{claim}[theorem]{Claim}
\newtheorem{conclusion}[theorem]{Sonu\c{c}}
\newtheorem{condition}[theorem]{Condition}
\newtheorem{conjecture}[theorem]{Conjecture}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Sonu\c{c}}
\newtheorem{criterion}[theorem]{Criterion}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Tan\i m}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{\"{O}rnek}
\newtheorem{exercise}[theorem]{\"{O}dev}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{notation}[theorem]{Notasyon}
\newtheorem{problem}[theorem]{Problem}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{\"{O}nerme}
\newtheorem{summary}[theorem]{Summary}
\newenvironment{proof}[1][Kan\i t]{\noindent\text{#1:} }{$\square$}
\newenvironment{remark}[1][Not]{\noindent\textbf{#1:} }{}
\newenvironment{solution}[1][\c{C}\"{o}z\"{u}m]{\noindent\text{#1:} }{}
\renewcommand{\dateseparator}{.}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6]
        \begin{axis}[width=10cm, height=10cm, axis equal image, clip=false, xticklabel style= 
{font=,below left }, yticklabel style={font=, left}, axis lines=middle,
            xmin=-1,xmax=5,
            ymin=-2,ymax=5,
            restrict y to domain=-15:15,
            xtick={1,3},ytick= 
            {0},
            xticklabels={1,3},yticklabels= 
            {0},
            axis line style={latex-latex},
            axis line style={->},
            x label style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},
                anchor=west,},
            y label style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},
                anchor=south},
            xlabel={$x$},
            ylabel={$y$}
            ]
            \draw[name path=A, dashed, very thick] (1,-2)-- (1,4);
            \draw[name path=B, dashed, very thick] (3,-2)-- (3,4);
            \addplot[gray, opacity=0.2] fill between [of = A and B, soft clip = {domain y 
            =-2:4}];
            \node at (2,2) {$B$};
            \node [anchor=north] at (axis cs:-0.25,-.07) {$ 0$};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

   \end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using subfiles it is possible to compile them independently of the main file using its preamble.

They should start as `\documentclass[./main.tex]{subfiles}`

See the following example. Put the next three files in the working directory.

This is the first subfile: `subfile_green.tex`. Compile first

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

%% File subfile_green.tex   
\documentclass[./main.tex]{subfiles} % changed <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6]
        \begin{axis}[width=10cm, height=10cm, axis equal image, clip=false, xticklabel style= 
            {font=,below left }, yticklabel style={font=, left}, axis lines=middle,
            xmin=-1,xmax=5,
            ymin=-2,ymax=5,
            restrict y to domain=-15:15,
            xtick={1,3},ytick= 
            {0},
            xticklabels={1,3},yticklabels= 
            {0},
            axis line style={latex-latex},
            axis line style={->},
            x label style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},
                anchor=west,},
            y label style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},
                anchor=south},
            xlabel={$x$},
            ylabel={$y$}
            ]
            \draw[name path=A, dashed, very thick] (1,-2)-- (1,4);
            \draw[name path=B, dashed, very thick] (3,-2)-- (3,4);
            \addplot[green, opacity=0.2] fill between [of = A and B, soft clip = {domain y  =-2:4}]; % green <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
            \node at (2,2) {$B$};
            \node [anchor=north] at (axis cs:-0.25,-.07) {$ 0$};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

with the output (single page) in `subfile_green.pdf`

[image: g]

This is the second subfile: `subfile_red.tex` (only changed the color}. Compile next.

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

%% File subfile_red.tex 
\documentclass[./main.tex]{subfiles} % changed <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6]
        \begin{axis}[width=10cm, height=10cm, axis equal image, clip=false, xticklabel style= 
            {font=,below left }, yticklabel style={font=, left}, axis lines=middle,
            xmin=-1,xmax=5,
            ymin=-2,ymax=5,
            restrict y to domain=-15:15,
            xtick={1,3},ytick= 
            {0},
            xticklabels={1,3},yticklabels= 
            {0},
            axis line style={latex-latex},
            axis line style={->},
            x label style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},
                anchor=west,},
            y label style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},
                anchor=south},
            xlabel={$x$},
            ylabel={$y$}
            ]
            \draw[name path=A, dashed, very thick] (1,-2)-- (1,4);
            \draw[name path=B, dashed, very thick] (3,-2)-- (3,4);
            \addplot[red, opacity=0.2] fill between [of = A and B, soft clip = {domain y =-2:4}]; % red <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
            \node at (2,2) {$B$};
            \node [anchor=north] at (axis cs:-0.25,-.07) {$ 0$};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

with the output  (single page) in `subfile_red.pdf`

[image: r]

Finally compile `main.tex` that includes the two subfiles.

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

% File main.tex

\documentclass[10pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsfonts}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage[ddmmyyyy]{datetime}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
%\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xypic}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[turkish,shorthands=:!]{babel}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{10}

\usepackage{subfiles}

\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes, arrows, arrows.meta, 
    decorations.markings, patterns, datavisualization}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween, polar}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgflibrary{shapes.geometric}

\pgfplotsset{my style/.append style={axis x line=middle, axis y line=
        middle, xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$}, axis equal }}

\linespread{1.5}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Teorem}[section]
\newtheorem{acknowledgement}[theorem]{Acknowledgement}
\newtheorem{algorithm}[theorem]{Algorithm}
\newtheorem{axiom}[theorem]{Axiom}
\newtheorem{case}[theorem]{Case}
\newtheorem{claim}[theorem]{Claim}
\newtheorem{conclusion}[theorem]{Sonu\c{c}}
\newtheorem{condition}[theorem]{Condition}
\newtheorem{conjecture}[theorem]{Conjecture}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Sonu\c{c}}
\newtheorem{criterion}[theorem]{Criterion}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Tan\i m}
\newtheorem{exercise}[theorem]{\"{O}dev}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{notation}[theorem]{Notasyon}
\newtheorem{problem}[theorem]{Problem}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{\"{O}nerme}
\newtheorem{summary}[theorem]{Summary}
\newenvironment{proof}[1][Kan\i t]{\noindent\text{#1:} }{$\square$}
\newenvironment{remark}[1][Not]{\noindent\textbf{#1:} }{}
\newenvironment{solution}[1][\c{C}\"{o}z\"{u}m]{\noindent\text{#1:} }{}
\newenvironment{example}[1][\"{O}rnek]{\noindent\textbf{#1:} }{}
\renewcommand{\dateseparator}{.}
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\normalfont\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftsecpagefont}{\normalfont\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftdotsep}{1}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

\fancyhead[L]{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}

\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{
    \markright{{\thesubsection.\ #1}}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}

\let\oldsection\section% Store \section in \oldsection
\renewcommand{\section}{\cleardoublepage\oldsection}

\begin{document}
    \frontmatter
    \title{\textbf{TOPOLOGY}}
    \author{Dr}
    \date{\today }
    \maketitle
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \tableofcontents
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \clearpage\null\thispagestyle{empty}
    \renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}} \clearpage
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
    \mainmatter
    
    \subfile{subfile_green} % first subfile <<<<<<<<<<<<
    
    \subfile{subfile_red} % second subfile <<<<<<<<<<<
    
\end{document}
```

After compiling the outcome is (plus a title page)

[image]

Comment: First of all thanks for your answer. In fact, the code I shared above is working on one computer, while it gives an error on another computer. Also i am using the subfile code using the secientific workplace 5.5 program, so i need preamble of the subfile. I also wonder why it works on one computer and not on the other. This code was working before I formatted my computer, but after formatting it didn't work.

Comment: @Mehmet Onat The code in the preamble of a subfile will be ignored. There are two possibilities.
• If LATEX is run on the subfile, the line `\documentclass[..]{subfiles}` is
replaced by the preamble of the main file (including its `\documentclass`
command). The rest of the subfile is processed normally.
• If LATEX is run on the main file, the subfile is loaded like with an `\input`
command, except that the preamble of the subfile up to` \begin{document}`
as well as \end{document} and the lines following it are **ignored**.

Comment: If you just install miktex, your code doesn't work. It gives a error Emergency stop. What would be the reason? I think the problem is caused by miktex

Comment: @Mehmet Onat (1) you have to install all packages (2) Use pdflatex. One of the packages is not compatible with lualatex.

Comment: The code causing the error is ''soft clip = {domain y =-2:4}''

Comment: I found the cause of the error, \usepackage[turkish,shorthands=:!]{babel}. Instead it is need to use this code,: \usepackage[turkish,shorthands=off]{babel}